# Cancel close outlook form region

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-2007

I was wondering how you can cancel the closing of an outlook form region.

I want to display a dialog to tell the user that the form is incomplete and a yes no option for continuing. But because `FormRegionClosed` event has a generic `EventArgs` object rather than a more specific version there is no equivalent I can see to the win forms e.Cancel property.

In case it helps, the form region is displayed on a contact and this is outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cancel the form region closing. Even if you go up to a higher level ([`Inspector.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865374.aspx)) - you still can't cancel the closing.